# Can FTDI device port number be known without opening the connection?

Tags: c++, usb, ftdi

I want to list FTDI ports with their description, here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ftd2xx.h"

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    DWORD numDevs = 0, i = 0;
    FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE *ftDevList = NULL;
    FT_STATUS ftStatus;

    /* Get the number of FTDI D2XX devices connected to the system.
     * This also trigs in the driver the creation of a list which we later get
     * using FT_GetDeviceInfoList(). */
    if( (ftStatus = FT_CreateDeviceInfoList(&numDevs)) != FT_OK )
    {
        std::cout << "FT_CreateDeviceInfoList failed with error " << ftStatus << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    if( numDevs != 0 )
    {
        /* Ask the FTDI USB driver the list of all numDevs FTDI D2XX devices which
         * are plugged in the PC: */
        ftDevList = (FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE *)
                        malloc(numDevs * sizeof(FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE));
        if ( !ftDevList )
        {
            std::cout << "Could not get device list" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }

        if ( (ftStatus = FT_GetDeviceInfoList(ftDevList, &numDevs)) != FT_OK )
        {
            std::cout << "FT_GetDeviceInfoList failed with error " << ftStatus << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }

        for ( i = 0 ; i < numDevs ; i++ )
        {
            FT_HANDLE ftOpenHandle;
            if ((ftStatus = FT_Open(i,&ftOpenHandle)) == FT_OK)
            {
                LONG lComPortNumber = 0;
                if ( (ftStatus = FT_GetComPortNumber(ftOpenHandle,&lComPortNumber)) == FT_OK) 
                {
                    if (lComPortNumber == -1)
                    {
                        // No COM port assigned
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        std::cout << "COM" << lComPortNumber << " is " << ftDevList[i].Description << std::endl;  
                    }
                }
                else 
                {
                    std::cout << "FT_GetComPortNumber failed with error " << ftStatus << std::endl;
                    return 1;
                }
                FT_Close(ftOpenHandle);
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "FT_Open failed with error " << ftStatus << std::endl;
                return 1;
            }
        }

        free( ftDevList );
    }
    // else: No need to build this empty list. We have all the information: "there is 
    // no USB FTDI device plugged in the PC".

    return 0;
}
```

However, as you can see, this opens the port `FT_Open`/`FT_Close`. I'm just surprised the port number is not part of `FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE`...why do I need to open the port to retrieve this basic information? Using WIN32 API for instance, ports can be enumerated without being "opened"...is there no way to do this using FTDI driver?

Comment: Are you aware of FT_GetDeviceInfoDetail? I never used it myself but it is mostlikely the thing you are looking for: https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/ProgramGuides/D2XX_Programmer's_Guide(FT_000071).pdf

Comment: @ChristianB.: `FT_GetDeviceInfoDetail` parameters are actually the same fields as `FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE` struct given by my call to `FT_GetDeviceInfoList`. There's a lot of information here but not the COM port number (when I read the doc first time I thought "LocID" would contain the COM port number but it does not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the libusbp library is capable of detecting USB virtual COM ports and listing them without doing any I/O on Windows, Linux, or macOS.  See the `lsport` example:

https://github.com/pololu/libusbp/blob/master/examples/lsport/lsport.cpp

Answer (score 0):

In short, using the FTDI DLL, you can only read the COM port string after you have opened it. Worse still, if opened by another process, FT_CreateDeviceInfoList returns nothing. Just useless!
It's not great if you want to display available ports and grey out the ones that are already open.

But.. There is a trick,
You can access what you see in device manager at anytime without 'disruption'.
Here you can find a cached copy of the COM port and FTDI Serial number -->even when the connection is open<--

Steps:

- Make a list from the device manager of COM ports (This contains
  FTDI serial numbers and COM ports)
- Make a list from FTDI
  FT_CreateDeviceInfoList (This contains FTDI serial numbers)
- Compare the
  two lists. Any FTDI ports that do NOT appear in the
  FT_CreateDeviceInfoList are OPEN

I don't know in C++ how to do this, but in C# on Windows, you get the idea..

```
using System.Management;
...
public class DeviceManagerInfoStruct
{
    public required string? Caption { get; set; }
    public required string? Service { get; set; }
    public required string? DeviceID { get; set; }
}
...
IEnumerable<DeviceManagerInfoStruct?> ports;
// Build a query that selects all devices where PNPClass=="Ports"  (Class in device manager)
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-pnpentity#properties
using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE PNPClass like 'Ports'"))
{
    // Extract all records found in the device manager under 'Ports (LPT & COM)'
    var Ports_LPT_COM = searcher.Get().Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().ToList();
    // Populate the ports struct with DeviceManager information
    ports = Ports_LPT_COM.Select( dm_info =>
        new DeviceManagerInfo
        {
            Caption = dm_info["Caption"]?.ToString(),
            Service = dm_info["Service"]?.ToString(),
            DeviceID = dm_info["DeviceID"]?.ToString()
        } );
}
// Print results
foreach (var port in ports)
    Console.WriteLine($"Caption={port?.Caption}, Service={port?.Service}, DeviceID={port?.DeviceID}");
```

I get the following results.

```
Caption=ECP Printer Port (LPT1), Service=Parport, DeviceID=ACPI\PNP0401\5
Caption=Communications Port (COM1), Service=Serial, DeviceID=ACPI\PNP0501\0
Caption=USB Serial Port (COM9), Service=FTSER2K, DeviceID=FTDIBUS\VID_0403+PID_6001+FTDWGWNQA\0000
Caption=USB Serial Port (COM13), Service=FTSER2K, DeviceID=FTDIBUS\VID_0403+PID_6014+FT9UOLFJA\0000
Caption=Standard Serial over Bluetooth link (COM6), Service=BTHMODEM, DeviceID=BTHENUM\{00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}_LOCALMFG&0002\8&31A2A89E&0&D8373B6C9E26_C00000000
Caption=Standard Serial over Bluetooth link (COM7), Service=BTHMODEM, DeviceID=BTHENUM\{00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}_LOCALMFG&0000\8&31A2A89E&0&000000000000_00000000
Caption=USB Serial Port (COM18), Service=FTSER2K, DeviceID=FTDIBUS\VID_0403+PID_6010+FT9OETCDA\0000
Caption=USB Serial Port (COM19), Service=FTSER2K, DeviceID=FTDIBUS\VID_0403+PID_6010+FT9OETCDB\0000
```

If Service==FTSER2K, then its an FTDI
You have COM number in [Caption]
You have FTDI Serial number in [DeviceID]

**SerialPort lockups?**
There is talk of opening/closing too quickly causing lockups
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31492253/1271896

However, the later releases of System.IO.Ports.SerialPort on NuGet have been worked on a lot since - so this may not be an issue any more?
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/commits/main/src/libraries/System.IO.Ports/src/System/IO/Ports

**Update - Two last 'Gochas'**
The DeviceID reported by the Device manager can suffix the FTDI serial number for single UART chips with an 'A'. It is not the same serial number as reported by the FTDI DLL. For example:
VID_0403+PID_6010+FT9OETCD**A**\0000
*Also..*
When using the FTDI DLL, know that when a USB FTDI device is removed, all devices seem to re-enumerate, and for 2 seconds, the FT_GetDeviceInfoDetail API returns just blank entries!

IMHO, the whole thing is a bit of a dog's breakfast.
Since it was chopped out of the .NET framework and moved to its own NuGet package, many fixes have been added to the System.IO.Ports 'SerialPort' class. The 'exception on Open()' test will save you code complexity. Is it better than parsing long device manager strings? I don't know the answer to that. Comments?